# Page seems to be stuck in an specific height, I can't create more bottom space

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am trying to clone some website to improve my skills, but I have encounter a problem, the page seems to be stuck in an specific height and when I try to add more html it just disappear  (it does not disappear, it's added at the top of the page behind the background image). I really want to know what is causing this and how to fix it without messing with the background image.

```
.center{
  text-align: center;
}
*{
  margin 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a:link {
    color: inherit;
}

a:visited {
  color:inherit;
}

a:hover {
    color: #ea7640;
}

a:active {
    color:inherit;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#wrapper {
    background-image: url("https://66.media.tumblr.com/f79df0dd538fc53292fe1aac7cd54daf/tumblr_oga789rskz1vxey6qo1_1280.png");
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 70%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: 3em;

}

nav {
  background-color: #312822;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right:-8px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 25px;
  color: #bdb9b7;
}
#proyecto {
  color: #ea7640;
}
.texto {
  color: #ea7640;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#logo {
  margin-top: 4em;
}

#text{
  margin-top: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#marca {
  margin-top: 10em;
  font-style: italic;
}

#wrapper2{
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 1000px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 700px;
  left: 0;
}
#wrapper2 ul {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

**Demo**: http://codepen.io/njwda/pen/PbwaOV

Answer (score 1):

Just erase `position: fixed` from your wrapper elements - that way the elements will simply appear below each other, as they are supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Your image has `position: fixed`, so the other content by default has property `position: static` and located under the image. If you want to see your new content, your should use one of the following properties for it:

```
position: absolute;
position: fixed;
position: relative;
```

For example try to add new `<h1 style = 'position: relative;'>Test</h1>` to your HTML.
Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/o589ynts/

Good luck